# Custom Sorting using Factor and Transform no longer works?

Tags: r

As of a few months ago, I was using transform and factor to custom sort variables in non-alphabetical order. Suddenly, this just stopped working? I haven't changed the code at all, and I am literally copying and pasting code that used to work. I tried updating both R and RStudio to the newest versions and that didn't help. I was wondering if anyone could give me insight into why this isn't working? Here are all of the variations of code I have tried:

```
data$Include <- factor(data$Include, levels=c('YES', 'No'))

data$Include <- factor(data$Include, levels=c('YES', 'No', ordered=TRUE))

data$Include <- factor(data$Include, c('YES', 'No'))

data$Include <- factor(data$Include, c('YES', 'No', ordered=TRUE))

data <- transform(data, Include = factor(Include, levels = c('YES', 'No')))

data <- transform(data, Include = factor(Include, levels = c('YES', 'No', ordered=TRUE)))

data <- transform(data, Include = factor(Include, levels = c('YES', 'No'), ordered=TRUE))

This data is coming from a .csv file, which has headers, including 'Include', which only has YES and No as an option. To upload the file, I tried both:

data <- read.csv('file.csv')

data <- read.csv('file.csv', header=TRUE)
```

Also, I tried to sort multiple different columns within the same file, and that didn't work, and I also tried to sort other files, and they didn't work either. I can't stress it enough that this used to work fine for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You claim the variations above do not work. What exactly do you mean? What do you want?

Comment: @Onyambu Hi! I want it to sort that column by row variable (so sort so that all of the 'YES's are first, an all of the 'No's are second). (So take from YES No No No YES YES to YES YES YES No No No, etc)

Comment: But in all of the above there is no sorting done

Comment: @Onyambu Ok but that code literally used to order my data based on the levels, as listed, and exactly as I presented. So I don't know if changes have been made to the base code to make this not the case anymore, but if you have another suggestion...

Comment: No it did not. Probably your data was ordered before you applied the code. The code does not in any way order your data. You sould consider doing `data$Include <- factor(data$Include, levels=c('YES', 'No', ordered=TRUE))` then do `dat1<-data[order(data$Include), ]` Now check `dat1` is ordered